# How to convert a boxed trait into a trait reference?

Tags: rust

I have the following code that tries to take a reference to a trait object from a boxed trait:

```
trait T {}

struct S {}

impl T for S {}

fn main() {
    let struct_box: Box<S> = Box::new(S {});
    let struct_ref: &S = &struct_box;

    let trait_box: Box<T> = Box::new(S {});
    let trait_ref: &T = &trait_box;
}
```

The compiler returns the following error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::boxed::Box<T>: T` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:12:25
   |
12 |     let trait_ref: &T = &trait_box;
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `T` is not implemented for `std::boxed::Box<T>`
   |
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `T`
```

How do I properly borrow `&T` from `Box<T>`?

Comment: See also [Convert boxed trait to mutable trait reference in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41540882/155423)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Box<T>` implements [the `AsRef<T>` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html), which provides the method `as_ref()`, so you can turn it into a reference that way:

```
let trait_ref: &T = trait_box.as_ref();
```

Normally, [*deref coercions*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch15-02-deref.html) mean that you don't usually need to write this out explicitly. If you pass a value of type `Box<T>` to a function that takes `&T`, the compiler will insert the conversion for you. If you want to call one of the methods on `T` that takes `&self`, the compiler will insert the conversion for you. **However**, deref coercion doesn't apply to a cast to a trait object type (the compiler will choose an unsizing coercion instead, which is what happens in your example).

Comment: Could you explain further why an unsizing coercion is chosen in this scenario as opposed to a deref coercion? Section 10.7 "Type coercions" of the Rust reference doesn't give an explanation.

Answer (score 8):

Borrow the contents of the `Box`, rather than the `Box` itself:

```
let trait_ref: &T = &*trait_box;
```

The reason the line involving `&S` works is because the only way for Rust to get from `Box<S>` to `&S` is via "deref coercion"; that is, it repeatedly dereferences the value until either the types match, or it can't dereference any further.

Coercing to a trait object, on the other hand, isn't done using dereferencing at all; it involves constructing a new pointer directly from the given one.  If it can't do that, it fails.

Comment: My understanding of deref coercion is that the compiler will call `deref()` for as many times as possible & needed, until the types match. Here, `trait_box.deref()` does yield the type `dyn T`.

I understand that type `&dyn T` is a fat pointer, which is not what is stored in the `Box`'s data structure. However wouldn't the compiler have enough information to construct that fat pointer for me? The fact that calling `trait_box.deref()` works fine suggests that it can. Is there a good reason why you wouldn't want that to be implicitly done?