# How do you pass a Boxed trait object to a function?

Tags: rust, serial-port, boxing

I am trying to use rust (on Linux) to write simple commands to a serialport and return the response. I am using the [serialport](https://docs.rs/serialport/4.0.1/serialport/) crate. I wanted to do reading in a separate function from Main. I initialize my serialport in main:

```rust
let mut device = serialport::new(format!("/dev/ttyUSB{}", port), 115_200)
    .flow_control(serialport::FlowControl::None)
    .open()
    .expect(&errorMsg);
```

This seems to work fine. However, I notice that if i hover the cursor over device, vscode tells me the following:

`std::boxed::Box<dyn serialport::SerialPort>`

Then I have a function I want to use to read from the serialport:

```rust
fn read_until_new_prompt<T: serialport::SerialPort>(device: &mut T) -> Result<Vec<String>, serialport::Error>{
...
}
```

and I try calling it from main:

```rust
...
read_until_new_prompt(&mut device);
...
```

But this does not work. Cargo tells me that:

> error[E0277]: the trait bound `Box<dyn SerialPort>: SerialPort` is not satisfied

> the trait `SerialPort` is not implemented for `Box<dyn SerialPort>`

I am unsure about what is the right way to handle this then. I have seen examples around the web of people doing pretty much exactly what I am attempting here, but their examples neither implies this problem or suggests any workarounds. I am pretty sure *I* am just thinking about this all wrong, but I come from a C/C#/JS/Python/Java etc. background, and am just trying to learn this relatively new, awesome language.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a boxed trait into a trait reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49218474/how-to-convert-a-boxed-trait-into-a-trait-reference)